# ASP.Net Routing in asp.net web-forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using ASP.Net web form Routing for my website but i want to make it more structure & hide all the Querystring ID's with proper Structure like `Language/Category/PageName-Title`
example: `www.abc.com/en/sports/cricket-world-cup`

but with my current routing technique i am able to make it work as

`www.abc.com/en/1/13/cricket-world-cup`

`domain/english-folder/language-id/page-id/page-title`

How can i make it more structured as `` `www.abc.com/en/sports/cricket-world-cup ``

Since i have few  Query-string i designed it this way

```
    //For Page.aspx
    routes.MapPageRoute("Page_Route", "en/page/{LID}/{PID}/{PageName}", "~/en/Page.aspx", false,
                new RouteValueDictionary {
                    { "LID", "0"},
                    { "PID", "0" },
                    { "PageName", "Page-not-found" }},
                new RouteValueDictionary {   
                    { "LID", "[0-9]{1,8}" },
                    { "PID", "[0-9]{1,8}" },
                });
```

Result of above Routing get me Friendly URL like this
`www.abc.com/en/1/13/cricket-world-cup`

But i want to further structure the URL like the one in example.

`www.abc.com/en/sports/cricket-world-cup`

Example: This url i found is more structure/
`http://www.thenational.ae/news/world/europe/turkey-providing-jobs-a-future-for-more-greeks`

How can i implement the same structure are they passing `querystrings` as hiddenfields. Please suggest best approach for such url.

another example is http://mashreqbank.com/uae/en/corporate/lending/trade-finance.aspx

they are using asp.net but i am not sure if it is ASP.Net MVC or ASP.Net webform.

I have been struggling with this kind of routing for quite long and even i cant find a complete example which can take into consideration more than one query-string as most of the example are based on one query-string.

Any help from coding gurus with example would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
Let us take this Table into consideration which i use to store page name, title, handler, language regions etc.. This is just a demo table & doesnt resemble the actual website which i am refering to for sample structured url. I am not even sure if they are going it using URL routing or these are actual physical folder & files like old style website where you create actual folder and place files in their etc..

```
Page_ID     Page_Name               Page_Title              Page_Handler        Parent_Page_ID  Language_ID     Region_ID
1           Home                    Home                    index.aspx              0               1               uae
2           Personal                Personal                index.aspx              0               1               uae
3           Accounts & Deposits     Accounts & Deposits     index.aspx              2               1               uae
4           Current Account         Current Account         current-account.aspx    3               1               uae
5           Current Gold Accounts   gold Account            gold-account.aspx       3               1               uae
6           Easy Saver              Easy Saver Account      saver-account.aspx      3               1               uae
7           Fixed Deposits          Fixed Account           fixed-account.aspx      3               1               uae
8           Loans                   Loans                   index.aspx              2               1               uae
9           Personal Loans          Personal Loans          index.aspx              8               1               uae
10          car Loans               car Loans               car-loan.aspx           8               1               uae
```

website example for above structure http://mashreqbank.com/

We can use a common page handler if the page design is same this is what i am assuming let us say `page.aspx`,

Pleae feel to make changes to structure and data inorder to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply have something like:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
    "article-route",
    "en/{category}/{pageName}",
    "~/en/page.aspx");
```

And then on `en/page.aspx` you can access the category and pageName, assuming you have a query to find the correct article based on those two variables:

```
string category = Page.RouteData.Values["category"] as string;
string pageName = Page.RouteData.Values["pageName"] as string;
```

Though, if you can't identify a page simply by `category` and `pageName` (which seems true per your updated question), you may need the `id` in the route. In this case, you can ignore the `category` and `pageName` route values as they are only there for a nice-looking URL. The only parameter we care about is the `id` since that is how you identify an article. For example, here are three examples of various routes

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
    "uae-route",
    "uae/en/{category}/{id}/{pageName}",
    "~/en/index.aspx");

routes.MapPageRoute(
    "gbr-route",
    "gbr/en/{category}/{id}/{pageName}",
    "~/en/index.aspx");

routes.MapPageRoute(
    "account-route",
    "en/{id}/{pageName}",
    "~/en/current-account.aspx");

//then on en/index.aspx and current-account.aspx
int pageId= 0;
if (Int32.TryParse(Page.RouteData.Values["id"] as string, out pageId)) {
    // get the page details (including parent page id and language id if needed)
    // where Page_ID=pageId. 
}
```

From the sounds of it though, you want to do the first example above, meaning you'll need a way to pull articles by simply `category` and `pageName` and not any type of `id`.

**UPDATE:** You don't need to create a route for each path... that's the whole point of routing. If you have multiple handlers, then you'll at least need a path for each handler (`.aspx` page).

It'd be easiest to use an `id` in the URL, because according to your data structure, that is the only way to identify the page you want to pull. So let's use your example, using these routes:

> www.abc.com/en/personal
>
> www.abc.com/en/personal/acounts-deposits/
>
> www.abc.com/en/personal/acounts-deposits/current-account
>
> www.abc.com/en/personal/acounts-deposits/current-gold-account
>
> www.abc.com/en/personal/acounts-deposits/easy-saver

You have one route:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
    "personal_route",
    "en/personal/{category}/{pageName}",
    "~/personal.aspx",
    false,
    new RouteValueDictionary { { "category", string.Empty }, {"pageName", string.Empty}}); //allow for no values
```

And the `personal.aspx` has the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string category = Page.RouteData.Values["category"] as string;
    string pageName = Page.RouteData.Values["pageName"] as string;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(category)) {
        //no category... must be the /personal route. handle that    
    }
    else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pageName))  {
        //no page name, just load the category page content
        //Psuedo query against your non-existant data schema
        //SELECT * FROM SiteContent WHERE Page_Handler='Personal' AND Page_Category=category && Page_URL=""
    }
    else {
        //SELECT * FROM SiteContent WHERE Page_Handler='Personal' AND Page_Category=category && Page_URL=pageName
    }
}
```

As you can see, your problem is you have no way to identify pages without the IDs. You'd need to replace all those IDs in your table with unique URLs. It's doable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply how can i resolve it if i have to show page hierarchy in url like `Parent_Page/Child_Page/Title` i mean page can be 1,2 or 3 levels down for example this url `http://mashreqbank.com/uae/en/corporate/lending/project-finance.aspx`

Comment: Shouldn't be any different. You can setup multiple routes that all route to the same place with same parameters with different route urls. I've done that for different news urls but in the end they were all processed by same aspx file. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I have updated my question with a sample database... to give a more clear structure .. Please ignore the handler file as most of it is `index.aspx` i can use different or one handler file for each section if page design is different for each section otherwise i can use just one file `Page.aspx` for almost all the pages... Please suggest if anything need to be changed or what approach should i take to get desired routing.. Appreciate your response.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker added some more details in answer. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker if you want to do routes without the `{id}` then you'll need a way to lookup pages based simply on the URL, which according to your table structure, you can't (looking up by category and page-name, like by the variables I show in first part of answer). You'd have to fix that first.

Comment: I want to achieve my routing as `www.abc.com/en/home
www.abc.com/personal` `www.abc.com/en/personal/acounts-deposits/`
 `www.abc.com/en/personal/acounts-deposits/current-account`
Assuming i want to one route to handle all these page requests for `personal` section. How can i make these bath in global.asx `routes.MapPageRoute("route_personal", "en/{path}/",
    "~/en/personal.aspx"); I generate my path using CTE query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d086/45 which i want to pass to `{path}` but my problem is that each path is different & then i need to generate different route for each path...

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker updated... I don't know what else advice I can offer. I think you problem is your data schema doesn't allow for the solution you want. Easiest solution is just to use ONE `id` to find a page then rest of route parameters are just for show... like it appears SO uses.

Comment: @Mike.., I will mark your answer as correct with one request  if you can point me to correct database schema for this kind of website or recommendation for designing database table for website with similar routing ...

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker it will depend, though perhaps just 2 adding columns to your pages table `category` and `pageUrl`, where pageUrl would be the `Page_Title` just url-safe (`current-gold-account` for `Current Gold Account`).